# Has anyone used Ruby/Rails with a Sales Logix database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, saleslogix

Has anyone used Ruby/Rails with a Sales Logix database?

Comment: You might want to re-phrase this question to be more specific and not result in a yes/no answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://www.2020software.com/products/Sage_SalesLogix_System_Requirements.asp) says SalesLogix runs on MS SQL Server or Oracle, both of which can connect with Rails through ActiveRecord.

[Here](http://piao-tech.blogspot.com/2008/02/using-activerecord-with-microsoft-sql.html) is a page that details setting up for MS SQL (which is what is more likely to be running on).